# Silverlight: Setting an Image source to MemoryStream

Tags: silverlight

My application receives a  jpeg file as a `MemoryStream` from a webservice. I need assign the image to image.Source. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [here](http://www.joe-stevens.com/2009/06/03/set-silverlight-image-source-from-byte-array/) it is described:

```
void proxy_GetImageCompleted(object sender, GetImageCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(e.Result);
    BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
    b.SetSource(stream);
    imgImage.Source = b;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The System.Windows.Controls.Image.Source property is of type System.Windows.Media.ImageSource
A System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage is derived from ImageSource.

And BitmapImage has a SetSource(Stream streamsource) method.

So with the following code you can add an image from a stream:

```
Stream inStream = [your MemoryStream];

BitmapImage tempImage = new BitmapImage();
tempImage.SetSource(inStream);

YourControlsImage.Source = tempImage;
```

MSDN links:

[Image.Source Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

[BitmapSource.SetSource Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsource%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

[BitmapImage Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)